# QGIS CSV 54,000 rows long- only some points show on map while others do not

Tags: qgis, csv

I have added a CSV with around 54,000 rows. When importing only some of the points display on the map while others do not. If I select a random row from my attribute table and zoom to selection, It will take me to the spot on the map where that point should be but the point is not visible? Any fixes to this?

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking the layer and export to geopackage?

Comment: Just tried that but still same thing.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the structure of the CSV for at least one of the features that does not appear on the map canvas?

Comment: Please provide coordinate examples of features that are visible, and of some which aren't.